# Is there a notion of compactness that implies sequentially compact and paracompact?

Tags: general-topology

In my research, I work with the space $X$ that it is sequentially compact and paracompact. Is there a notion of compactness that implies sequentially compact and paracompact. Note that $X$ is not metrizable.

Answer (score 2):

Even the strongest form of compactness (compactness itself) does not imply sequential compactness. All covering axioms that I know of that can be seen as "notions of compactness" (a somewhat vague notion in itself) are implied by compactness, so the same examples that show "compact" $\nrightarrow$ "seq. compact" also show the same non-implication for that other compactness notion.